# How to move cursor to parent inside a contenteditable form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

Here was my attempt: it almost works, except that it now puts the cursor before or after the first span in the editable container, rather than the one your cursor was in.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

div.onkeydown = fixCursor;
div.onclick = fixCursor;

function fixCursor () {
  //get current selection and the node it's in
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  var container = selection.anchorNode;

  //if it's a text node, get it's parent instead
  if (selection.anchorNode.nodeType == 3)
    container = selection.anchorNode.parentElement;

  //if the container shouldn't be edited
  if (container.classList.contains('noediting')) {
    console.log('no editing', selection.anchorOffset)

    //get element position
    var position = Array.from(div.childNodes).indexOf(container);
  
    //set new position to either before or after current element
    var newPosition = position;
    if (selection.anchorOffset > 0)
      newPosition = position+1;

    console.log(position,newPosition)

    //create/set a new selection (cursor)
    var cursor = document.createRange();
    cursor.setStart(container.parentElement, newPosition);
    cursor.collapse(true);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(cursor);

  }



}
```

```css
div span {
  color: #888
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>

  I am normal text <span class="noediting">no one should edit me</span> but you can edit me
<span class="noediting">but not me</span>

</div>
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

**edit:** I think I may have found a solution by getting the position of the container with indexOf, please tell if there's anything wrong with doing it that way